# Создание клавиатуры в телеграм боте Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Всем привет я не слишком опытен в программировании, и для себя решил написать бота в телеграме для помощи в учёбе.
Суть проблемы в том что я сделал главное меню с переходом в другие разделы (курсы 4,3 и тд.) в этих разделах (курсы) есть выбор из нескольких учебных предметов, я хочу сделать чтобы при выборе предмета пользователю приходило сообщение с ссылками на решение д/з, но при выборе предмета ничего не происходит.

```
        elif message.text == '‍ 4 Курс':
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
            obj1 = types.KeyboardButton('IT')
            obj2 = types.KeyboardButton('Економіка')
            obj3 = types.KeyboardButton('Меліорація')
            obj4 = types.KeyboardButton('Підприємництво')
            back = types.KeyboardButton('⬅ Назад')
            markup.add(obj1,obj2,obj3,obj4,back)
```

Вот список предметов и я думал реализовать это с помощью if, elif.
Вот пример:

```
        if message.text == 'IT':
            url1 = 'Практична №1: ' + 'url'
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, url1)

        elif message.text == 'Економіка':
            sti = open('AnimatedStickerCB.tgs')
            bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, sti)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Покищо тут пусто!')
```

Но при нажатии на кнопки бот не реагирует.

P.S. Были мысли что он попросту не может воспринимать такое количество кнопок, но я вроде как видел ботов с похожим функционалом.

Answer (score 0):

Тебе тут следует после url1 добавить, `reply_markup=markup`

```
if message.text == 'IT':
                url1 = 'Практична №1: ' + 'url'
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, url1, reply_markup=markup)
```

Comment: К сожалению не помогло, добавлял твой вариант с `if` и в отдельную функцию, добавлял и под разделами но бот все равно не реагирует. Не могу понять с чем это связано, пробовал сделать такое и с прошлыми ботами и они так же не реагируют.